# Octave malloc error

Tags: malloc, octave

I'm getting an error in a script that calls Octave that seems to be a memory leak or something. I have no idea how to debug it, as Octave is called from within the script, not working in Octave itself. The error message is as follows:

> octave(9568) malloc: *** error for
>   object 0x1033dd6e0: pointer being
>   freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug panic:
>   Abort trap -- stopping myself...
>   attempting to save variables to
>   `octave-core'... save to`octave-core'
>   complete

Can anyone suggest how to debug this?

Comment: Actually, it's called from c++ code, which is called from a bash script.